# Dynamic view setting same value for every view added dynamically

Tags: android

With following function, I am adding view dynamically. but through this, last call values to "addview" are getting set in all views. Like If i call addview function with "aaaa" in its 0 index it will add one view with aaaa name, and then again i call addview with "bbbb" in its 0 index it will add one more view but this time it set "bbbb" to previous view also. Means now both dynamically added view will have "bbbb" value in its edittext. Please help.

```
public void addView(String[] values) {
        layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) getActivity( ).getBaseContext( ).getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_fcp_child, null);

        ImageView ivRemove;
        EditText etName;
        RelativeLayout layDOB;
        final TextView tvDate;
        final Spinner spRelationship;

        tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_ins_dob);
        layDOB = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lay_ins_dob);
        etName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_ins_personname);
        etName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filterName, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(60)});
        ivRemove = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_fcp_remove);
        spRelationship = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sp_fcp_relationship);

        AdapterIDValue adapterRelations = new AdapterIDValue(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_selected_item_relation, alSRelationship);
        spRelationship.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapterRelations, R.layout.spinner_hint_relationship, getActivity()));

        etName.setText(values[0]);
        spRelationship.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(values[3]));
        tvDate.setText(values[1]);
        tvDate.setTag(values[2]);
        tvDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        try {
            layDynamic.addView(convertView);
        }catch (Exception sdf){
            System.err.print(sdf);
        }
        svMain.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
```

Comment: By the way, in Android, don't use `System.err.print(...)` but a logger like `Log.e(...)`

Comment: Thanks kevin. I will keep this in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create with `RecyclerView` OR `ListView`, or if you want to do with scroll view the generate dynamic Ids of every view, so you can solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to do this via dynamically added views. I just want to learn it.

Comment: Yes you can create with RecyclerView OR ListView, or if you want to do with scroll view the generate dynamic Ids of every view, so you can solve your problem.

Comment: I solved this problem by generating dynamic id for every view, as suggested by your last comment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `addview(...)` method will create a new adapter and set it to `spRelationship`. This new adapter replace the previous. You are not "adding views", you're "setting the views".

You have to set the adapter only once and change its data.

Comment: but every call to addview will be adding a new view with new spinner. So I'm setting adapter again. Isn't like this? And even edittext values are setting the same.

Comment: Ho sorry, I don't see this. What is `layDynamic` ?

Comment: layDynamic is the reference of parent layout. Under which I want to add dynamic views.

Comment: Yes... but what type it is?

Comment: Its LinearLayout with vertical orientation.